# How to take the power 2 of all elements in a pyspark featurevector?

Tags: pyspark, vector, user-defined-functions

I would like to raise all elements in the feature vector of my pyspark dataframe to the power 2.

Input dataframe:

```
schema = ["id", "vector"]
data = [
(0,[1.0,1.0,1.0]),
(1,[2.0,2.0,1.0]),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

Expected output:

```
schema = ["id", "vector"]
data = [
(0,[1.0,1.0,1.0]),
(1,[4.0,4.0,1.0]),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

I am especially having trouble looping through the feature vector. Could someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: why 1 remain as 1?

Comment: @Lamanus because 1^2 = 1

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform` function and `pow`.

```
df.withColumn('vector', f.transform('vector', lambda x: pow(x, 2))) \
  .show()

+---+---------------+
| id|         vector|
+---+---------------+
|  0|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]|
|  1|[4.0, 4.0, 1.0]|
+---+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. Nevertheless I get the following error. AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'transform('features', lambdafunction(POWER(x_1, 2), x_1))' due to argument data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array type, however, ''features'' is of struct>type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> type.;

Comment: note that in my code base the column 'vector' is acually called 'features'. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: and printSchema returns |-- features: vector (nullable = true) for the 'features' column.

Comment: 'features.values' returns the following error. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'